# How to check if a number is an element of a list in c#?

Tags: c#

In Python I can do this:

```
if 1 in [1, 2, 3, 1]:
    print("The number 1 is an element of this list.")
else:
    print("The number 1 is not an element of this list.")
```

I would like to do something similar in c#. So far I have been doing this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CheckMembership
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 1 };

            for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (myList[i] == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number 1 is an element of this list.");
                    break;
                }

                if (i == myList.Count - 1 && myList[i] != 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("The number 1 is not an element of this list.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more concise and efficient way of doing this, perhaps without a loop?

Comment: Your loop solution is a good start but it could use some work. Can you write a method with this signature `static bool Contains(List<int> items, int candidate) { ... }` that returns `true` if the candidate is in the list and `false` otherwise? If you can do so, then you can make your `Main` method much easier to read; `if(Contains(myList, 1)) ...`  As a beginner, always be asking yourself "can I extract this functionality to a method that solves one problem well?" That's how we make libraries of methods that compose to solve larger problems.

Comment: Now, as an answer points out, **someone already wrote that method for you**. But by writing the "basic" methods yourself *as a learning exercise*, you'll see that writing these library methods is not magic; they're written by developers, and you could be one of those developers.

Comment: Also I note that your solution is not quite right. What happens for instance if your list is *empty*? It should produce the message that `1 is not an element` because, well, the list is empty. But your program does not do so. Can you see how to fix the problem?

Comment: Thank you, Eric. Indeed I am a beginner, and just coding as a hobby, so I find your guidelines very helpful. I do enjoy writing my own methods as a learning tool, and then later I look for existing methods to make my code look nicer and work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `Contains()`:

```
if (myList.Contains(1))
{
}
```

Comment: To be clear, with this, the loop isn't needed at all, and it can be removed.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Type a number : ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int searchItem);
            List<int> items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 1 };

            //Determine if the item is in the list.
            Console.WriteLine($"{searchItem} {(items.Contains(searchItem) ? "is" : "isn't")} in the list");
            Console.WriteLine($"{searchItem} {(items.Where(item => item == searchItem).Any() ? "is" : "isn't")} in the list");
            Console.WriteLine($"{searchItem} {(items.Where(item => item == searchItem).Count() > 0 ? "is" : "isn't")} in the list");

            //Determine number of ocurrences
            Console.WriteLine($"{searchItem} is found {items.Where(item => item == searchItem).Count()} times in the list");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```